# How to handle disk full errors while logging in logback?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I am using slf4j+logback for logging in our application. Earlier we were using jcl+log4j and moved recently.

Due to the high amount of logging in our application, there is a chance of disk being full in production environment. In such cases we need to stop logging and application should work fine. What I found from the web is that we need to poll logback StatusManager for such errors. But this will add a dependency with logback for the application.
For log4j, I found that we can create an Appender which stops logging in such scenarios. That again will cause a application dependency with log4j.

Is there a way to configure this with only slf4j or is there any other mechanism to handle this?

Comment: I'm curious, what happens currently when the disk is full? Do exceptions bubble up from slf4j/logback? I would have thought the logging libraries wouldn't throw any exception at you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not have to do or configure anything. Logback is designed to handle this situation quite nicely. Once target disk is full, logback's `FileAppender` will stop writing to it for a certain short amount of time. Once that delay elapses, it will attempt to recover. If the recovery attempt fails, the waiting period is increased gradually up to a maximum of 1 hour. If the recovery attempt succeeds, `FileAppender` will start logging again.

The process is entirely automatic and extends seamlessly to `RollingFileAppender`. See also [graceful recovery.](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html#grace)

On a more personal note, graceful recovery is one my favorite logback features.

Comment: Will events be buffered or are those which happened while the disk was full, lost?

Comment: Events generated during IO failure are not buffered.

Comment: Will there be a notification in the log that log events have been dropped?

Comment: Can we stop before disk is full?

Answer (score 0):

You may try extending the slf4j.Logger class, specifically the info, debug, trace and other methods and manually query for the available space (via File.getUsableSpace() ) before every call.

That way you will not need any application dependency

Comment: File.getUsableSpace() will need log file location, which can vary according to the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

2 real options:

- add a cron task on linux (or scheduled one on windows) to clean up your mess (incl. gzip some, if need be).
- buy a larger hard disk and manually perform the maintenance
- +-reduce logging

Disk full is like OOM, you can't know what fails 1st when catch it. Dealing w/ out of memory (or disk) is by preventing it. There could be a lot of cases when extra disk space could be needed and the task failed.