# Stop Spring Boot application when logging fails (log4j2)

Tags: spring-boot, security, logging, log4j2

I have a standard Spring Boot micro service which uses Log4j2 for all logging.

I want to gracefully shutdown the spring boot app in case logging fails (eg. disk is full). Is there a way to set it up?

References:
[How to handle disk full errors while logging in logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596684/how-to-handle-disk-full-errors-while-logging-in-logback) --> This question doesn't answer this specific question.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FailoverAppender --> Reading the documentation of FailoverAppender, I am not sure if this is the correct one for the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need to do is to detect remaining disk through other mechanism rather than relying on the logger to detect it.
Spring boot actuator is used to provide many metrics including memory and disk. It enables external services to get metrics from the running instance through HTTP endpoints.

Looking at what actuator does to get disk space here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/system/DiskSpaceHealthIndicator.java
Shows that the mechanism is simple:

```
@Override
protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
    long diskFreeInBytes = this.path.getUsableSpace();
    if (diskFreeInBytes >= this.threshold.toBytes()) {
        builder.up();
    }
    else {
        logger.warn(LogMessage.format("Free disk space below threshold. Available: %d bytes (threshold: %s)",
                diskFreeInBytes, this.threshold));
        builder.down();
    }
    builder.withDetail("total", this.path.getTotalSpace()).withDetail("free", diskFreeInBytes)
            .withDetail("threshold", this.threshold.toBytes()).withDetail("exists", this.path.exists());
}
```

In you main application class you can check periodically for disk space and shut down the application context if disk space is below a specific threshold using the same mechanism as shown above. Shutting down the application can be such this:

```
int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(ctx, new ExitCodeGenerator() {
@Override
public int getExitCode() {
        // return the error code
        return 0;
    }
});

 
System.exit(exitCode);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, the logging failure might not just be because of disk errors. I gave disk full only as an example

Answer (score 0):

Every Appender is wrapped by an AppenderControl in Log4j 2. The AppenderControl catches any exceptions thrown by the Appender. Its default behavior is to get the error handler attached to the Appender and call its error() method. When that method returns it will check to see if the attribute "ignoreExceptions" is false (it defaults to true) and if so it will rethrow the exception.

Ideally you could implement your own error handler except the guy who wrote that code (me) forgot to make it configurable. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2927.

FailoverAppender was designed to wrap an appender and then fail over to another appender when an error occurs. This requires ignoreExceptions to be set to false on the target appender. You could copy FailoverAppender to create your own custom appender that instead performs a shutdown when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot comes with an actuator that has a (disabled by default) `shutdown` endpoint.
Basically when enabled this endpoint allows shutting down the spring boot application via the JMX or HTTP. This is by far the best way I know to shut down the spring boot application gracefully.

The source code of this endpoint is available [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/context/ShutdownEndpoint.java) and you can easily see that after all it calls `close` method on the application context.

Now to your question, I've never worked with log4j2, but as an idea, you could create your own appender that would wrap the real appender assigned to the loggers, it could catch the exception and call that `close` method (in this case it will have to maintain a reference to the application context as well)  or invoke the `shutdown` endpoint via JMX for instance. This could "complement" the answer provided by @rgoers who addresses the issue from the log4j2 standpoint.